# Golang + Postgres кодировка ошибки

Tags: windows, postgresql, golang

Столкнулся с проблемой при проверке подключения к БД через db.Ping(),при задании некорректных данных при подключении (что-то типа "user=postgres password=wrongpass dbname=testdb sslmode=disable") в файл выводится ошибка:

> pq: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно отображать эту информацию, пробовал менять кодировку командной строке, никакого толку.

Comment: Укажите ОС, пожалуйста. У Windows с этим постоянные проблемы.

Comment: Windows 7. В настройках постгреса server_encoding стоит utf8, ставлю в cmd chcp 65001  - ни какого толку(

Comment: Попробуйте включить английский язык в Postgres, если с ним нет проблем. Английские ошибки проще найти в интернете, а так же они не будут выходить за диапазон ASCII и в UTF-8 и в CP-1251 отображаться одинаково. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185134/1816872

Comment: спасибо,помогло!

Answer (score 2):

для нормальной работы консольного вывода под windows использую следующий батник:

```
chcp 65001
go run *.go
```

и обязательно в терминале выставляю шрифт Lucida.

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить вывод ошибки на английский язык, изменив файл postgresql.conf, как на этом видео:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjPtBN_1VdU

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)